# Using STL's list object for Stack creation

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, stl, stack

I want to create a list of stacks in C++ but the compiler gives me some error messages:

```
 #include <list>
    #include <stack>

    class cName
    {
        [...]
        list<stack> list_stack;
        [...]
    }
```

Errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: `stack` is itself a template. You need to use it with template arguments. You should also have `std::` in front of the type names, i.e. `std::list` and `std::stack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is a template, you need to use it with template arguments. For sample:

```
class cName
{
  typedef int ConcreteType;
  std::list<stack<ConcreteType> > list_stack;
                  ^^^^ use it with real type
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Stacks are also templated, so it should be

```
list<stack <...> > list_stack;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your stack to handle just one type, for example int, change `stack` in your code to `int`:

```
list<int> list_stack;
```

Otherwise you should create your own template type instead of using `stack`:

```
template <class T> 
class List
{
    list<T> list_stack;

    T top();
    void push(T v);
};
```